# if I only work with PHP files and nothing related to database then can I keep MySql service stopped in XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

if I only work with PHP files and nothing related to database then can I keep MySql service stopped in XAMPP?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can! Mysql is not a dependency of Apache.